# Clearing the cache in android

Tags: android, caching

I am making a web application in android/chrome using a framework similar to in which i add /edit or delte users. I send ajax call from jquery using the syntax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url of webserice here,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: CallSucceed,
        dataType: "json",
        failure: CallFailed
    });
```

After i add a new user the grid that displays the list of users does not refresh. however if i go to settings in my android device and clear cache of my web application and come to user page again the newly added user starts showing. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work untill and unless i clear the cache. This problem only comes on the screen where i send call to web service but where i send calls to local sqllite database no problem comes.....

Answer (score 0):

For clearing app cache call this function where u want.(Best way onDestory())

trimCache(this);

```
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
    try {
       File dir = context.getCacheDir();
       if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
          deleteDir(dir);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: handle exception
    }
 }

 public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
       String[] children = dir.list();
       for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
          if (!success) {
             return false;
          }
       }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
 }
```